# How can I set my device to display time in UTC?

Tags: clock, date-and-time, time-zones

I want to try thinking in UTC instead of my local time. There is no UTC region and no UTC time zone under the United States region.

How can I set my device so it always displays the time in UTC instead of my local time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now `Select time zone` has a sideways `...` that you can select `Select by UTC offset`; this is an alternate way you can select `UTC GMT +00:00` without selecting a region. (Android 10, 2022-02 patch.)

I assume that this is the same time that one uses for SSL certificates, which I'd imagine is probably UTC instead of GMT. I use this as well, and it mostly works. The only trouble I've had is getting re-certified with Microsoft's OAuth mail server.

Comment: Additional note: [according to Google/AOSP developer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36957647#comment89), this feature has been added since Android 9.0 Pie.

Answer (score 2):

Set your device to the Iceland region. Iceland has a single time zone with a UTC offset of +0, and they do not use DST. Other time zones that may work are listed [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/gmt).